# SSL Certificate Installation Caused Website to Stop Working

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, pear

So I had an SSL certificate, I bought one from a new company, through plesk, I installed the new one and then the website just stopped working completely.

The host company cant help, the developers we have dont know how to get it to work.

We essentially have a very large site crashed due to ssl installation.

There was no error, just a blank page, after turning on error reporting, Here is the error we are getting on the website when we go to the website url

> Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/usr/share/psa-pear/MDB2.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/:/tmp/) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/inc/general.php on line 7 Warning:
>   require_once(/usr/share/psa-pear/MDB2.php): failed to open stream:
>   Operation not permitted in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/inc/general.php on line 7 Fatal
>   error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'MDB2.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/psa-pear/') in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/inc/general.php on line 7

This started only when we installed the new certificate, changing back to the old one does not work, still the same error on the website

Comment: I'd say it's a coincidence, as certificates work on SSL layer, and you have a server configuration error unrelated to SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `php.ini`'s `basedir` setting to include `/usr/share/psa-pear/`.